# How sandbox , IDE, Workspace, testing tool are interrelated?

Tags: testing, ide

As I'm very new to testing anyone can explain how sandbox and workspace and testing tool, IDE interrelated ?

Explain with any example is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it depends".

Unfortunately, your question is too broad to really answer.

SHORT VERSION:

1) You'll usually test in an isolated, QA environment (rather than risking messing up a production system). This might be called a "Sandbox".

2) You might use an "IDE" (like Eclipse, or MSVS) to run "Unit Tests" (like JUnit tests for Java source).

The source and tests will be organized into "Projects".

The projects, in turn, might be contained in a "Workspace" (in the case of the Eclipse IDE).

Here is a tutorial that discusses some of this, in the context of Eclipse, Java and JUnit:

- http://vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Your particular scenario might differ wildly. Again, the subject is just too broad...

I hope that helps.